# Are Monks proficient in Darts?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, monk, proficiency

Monks get 10 darts as part of their starting equipment. Except it looks like they are only proficient in Simple Melee Weapons and Shortswords. Did I miss a rule somewhere?

Comment: Cue image of monks hanging out in the pub....

Comment: @mattdm Darts in D&D aren't like pub darts. They're more like mini-spears. http://www.comitatus.net/images/comitatusplum.jpg

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I see Simple Weapons under monk proficiencies, not Simple Melee Weapons. You should be fine.

Answer (score 21):

There are two different relevant entries in the Monk here. The first is their proficiencies. The second is what counts as a "Monk Weapon." The dart qualifies as the former, but not the latter.

First the Proficienies list:

> Weapons: Simple weapons, shortswords (PHB 77).

So yes! The monk can use the dart. However it doesn't count as a "Monk Weapon"

> ...monk weapons, which are shortswords and any simple **melee** weapons that don't have the two-handed or heavy property. (PHB 78 emphasis mine)

You can see the difference in these two lists. Monks *can* use the dart as it is a simple ranged weapon. *However*, they cannot use them with the Monk's martial arts class feature since they are not melee weapons.

Answer (score 7):

Simple Melee Weapons and shortswords are monk weapons, not proficiencies. So you can still get your proficiency bonus with darts but you can't use your monk abilities with them.